# In Quartz.NET, concurrent jobs scheduling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

In Quartz.NET, I want to get current executing jobs as a list.

```
var jobs = scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
```

But it didn't return an `IEnumerable` result. I can not make it `IEnumerable` to get `JobKeys`.

Actually I want to pause a scheduled job when the other one is starting to run. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: What does "it didn't return IEnumerable result" mean? Is it empty or null? According to the [docs](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/html/e68ced83-ceab-5b92-a923-d4d245689a82.htm) `IScheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs` returns `Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IJobExecutionContext>>` so maybe you are just missing an `await`?

Comment: Yes it returns Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IJobExecutionContext>>. But i can not use it in foreach loop and not get jobKey.

Comment: I want to use that method in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326726/scheduling-concurrent-jobs-in-quartz-net

Comment: As this method is async you need to use `var jobs = await scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();` to be able to iterate over the returned `IReadOnlyCollection<>`.